# Saving Command Line Edits to Same (Source) Text File

Tags: powershell

I love this website, which has been very helpful for me. This is my first question post as typically I can find answers quite readily on here.  This may be an issue of search terms that are somewhat ambiguous or perhaps I don't know the right terms to search for.  At any rate, it is bedtime, I have work tomorrow, so I thought I would ask the experts.

So:  I have been able to get quite a bit of data organization, formatting, and analysis done with VBA through Excel, but had one last issue: Excel left 11 tabs after some columns (due to 11 columns following it) when exported to a text file (text so that the host program can import it).  So I learned, mostly here, about **PowerShell**.

I was very excited to get the following code working earlier today:

```
gc s3_data.txt | % {$_ -replace 
“`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t”, “ “} | set-content S3_copy2.txt
```

The problem is that I then wanted to make this loop through all files in a folder.  I can get it to do that now, and output to a single file, but cannot get it to write over the *same, original* file.  In fact, this version outputs to an external file over and over and over again!

```
Get-ChildItem “C:\stuff\*.txt” | ForEach-Object{gc $_} `
| % {$_ -replace “`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t”, “ “}`
|out-file notthefileIwanttosaveto.txt
```

Here is one version of the code I have tried:

```
Get-ChildItem “C:\stuff\*.txt” | ForEach-Object{gc $_} `
{$SaveFile= $_.Path}| % {$_ -replace “`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t”, “ “}`
|out-file -filepath $savefile
```

Obviously that strategy, and several others, did not work and probably doesn't make sense, but hopefully you can see what I am trying to do.  In other words - how do I make the output file the same file it is reading from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pipeline like this

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\stuff\*.txt" | 
    % { (Get-Content $_) -replace "`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t", "" | Set-Content $_ }
```

As pointed out by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) you may want to specify the encoding when writing back your processed data. For UTF8 it could look like so

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\stuff\*.txt" | 
    % { (Get-Content $_) -replace "`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t", "" | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 $_ }
```

Comment: Please make it clear that `Set-Content` without `-Encoding` will use the system's default code page ("ANSI" encoding), irrespective of what the (typically automatically detected) input encoding was, so you may end up with differently encoded files (potentially with data loss).
It is also worth nothing that while this method is convenient, it requires reading a given file into memory in its entirety, and data loss can occur if writing back to the input file is interrupted (leaving aside the fact that file attributes aren't preserved).

Comment: Well I agree that modifying the file in-place is not the best way to do it but that's what the questioner struggled with as he specifically asked for it so I provided an answer which addresses that. I will add the point with the encoding as additional info - thx for that.

Comment: No argument that this can be a viable approach, assuming that one knows the limitations and pitfalls (which is why I pointed them out). On a side note, `Get-Help Set-Content` actually claims that the default encoding is (7-bit) ASCII, but I've found that not to be true.

Comment: On initial walk-through, this works on my test files!  I don't know the encoding, so now am learning about that.  Given these comments, I'll make a quick copy of the actual files (which may have different encoding than the ones I made to test this) and then test it out to make sure that I do not do damage.  Will report back shortly to tell you if it works for real.  Thank you both!  EDIT: UTF-8 based on this site: https://nlp.fi.muni.cz/projects/chared/

Comment: EDIT: uh oh - adding the encoding part filled my screen with red error messages "InvalidArgument... the input object cannot be bound to any parameters... the command does not take pipeline input..." will keep working

Comment: It did work splendidly without the -encoding, so did not have to worry about it.  Thank you both for saving me hours upon hours of work!

Comment: @Clock247: Glad to hear it worked for you; as for the encoding: UTF-8 must be called `UTF8` (case-insensitively, but without the `-`) when passed to `-Encoding`, as shown in this answer. That said, if you had passed an invalid-to-PowerShell encoding name such as `UTF-8`, you should've seen a _different_ error message, namely "Cannot convert value "UTF-8" to type...".